# Disappear my BottomNavigationBar and AppBar on the specific page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In the `home_screen.dart`, I added 5 of *bottomNavigationBar* to move easily to other pages. At the second tab(`Icons.directions_boat_filled`), when I tab this It shows the *AppBar* and *bottomNavigationBar* also.

However, the *GestureDetector* which moves to the `vessel_screen.dart`, I couldn't find any *AppBar* and *bottomNavigationBar* when I click this button.

How can I see the **AppBar and bottomNavigationBar** in the same way when I clicked the second bottomNavigationBar Icon?

Here is the `home_screen.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:shipda/constants.dart';
import 'package:shipda/screens/home/home_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:shipda/screens/license_screen/license_screen.dart';
import 'package:shipda/screens/parts_screen/parts_screen.dart';
import 'package:shipda/screens/tab_bar_screen/tab_bar_screen.dart';
import 'package:shipda/screens/vessel_screen/vessel_screen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final _authentication = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User? loggedUser;
  final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  var resultData;

  void getData() async {
    var result = await firestore
        .collection('user')
        .doc('vUj4U27JoAU6zgFDk6sSZiwadQ13')
        .get();

    setState(() {
      resultData = result.data();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
    getData();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() {
    try {
      final user = _authentication.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedUser = user;
        print(loggedUser!.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  // Bottom Navigation Bar 스크린 인덱스
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    HomeMain(),
    VesselScreen(),
    LicenseScreen(),
    PartsScreen(),
    TabBarScreen(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
  // ----

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          '쉽다로고',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: baseColor50,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: baseColor10,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      // 바텀네비게이션바
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: primaryColor50,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 0
                ? Icon(Icons.home)
                : Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: '홈',
          ),
          // This is the icon.
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 1
                ? Icon(Icons.directions_boat_filled)
                : Icon(Icons.directions_boat_outlined),
            label: '선박',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 2
                ? Icon(Icons.document_scanner)
                : Icon(Icons.document_scanner_outlined),
            label: '허가',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 3
                ? Icon(Icons.handyman)
                : Icon(Icons.handyman_outlined),
            label: '부품',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            label: '전체',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`home_main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:shipda/screens/vessel_screen/vessel_screen.dart';
import '../../constants.dart';
import '../vessel_screen/fishing_vessel/fishing_vessel_screen.dart';

class HomeMain extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeMain({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        height: 680,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: baseColor20,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              marginHeight22,
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  // 최근검색버튼
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: primaryColor20,
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: primaryColor20,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(12.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      height: 48,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.435,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '최근검색',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: primaryColor50,
                            fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
                            fontSize: titleSmall,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // 관심매물버튼
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: primaryColor20,
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: primaryColor20,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(12.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      height: 48,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.435,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '관심매물',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: primaryColor50,
                            fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
                            fontSize: titleSmall,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              marginHeight22,
              // 광고영역
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: primaryColor30,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(12.0),
                  ),
                ),
                height: 120,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '광고영역',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: titleLarge,
                      color: baseColor10,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              marginHeight22,
              // 선박판매 버튼
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: primaryColor50,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(12.0),
                  ),
                ),
                height: 48,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '내 선박 판매하기',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: titleMedium,
                      fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
                      color: baseColor10,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              marginHeight22,
              // 선박매물검색, 허가, 부품
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  // This is the button to move the vessel_screeen.dart
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      Get.to(() => VesselScreen());
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: baseColor10,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(12.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      height: 196,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.435,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '선박매물',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: titleLarge,
                                fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
                                color: baseColor50,
                              ),
                            ),
                            marginHeight4,
                            Text(
                              '검색하러가기',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: bodyLarge,
                                fontFamily: 'regular',
                                color: baseColor50,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      // 어업 허가
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: baseColor10,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(12.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        height: 90,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.435,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                '어업허가',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: titleLarge,
                                  fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
                                  color: baseColor50,
                                ),
                              ),
                              marginHeight4,
                              Text(
                                '매매',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: bodyLarge,
                                  fontFamily: 'regular',
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      marginHeight16,
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: baseColor10,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(12.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        height: 90,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.435,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                '부품',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: titleLarge,
                                  fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
                                  color: baseColor50,
                                ),
                              ),
                              marginHeight4,
                              Text(
                                '중고부품거래',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: bodyLarge,
                                  fontFamily: 'regular',
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              marginHeight22,
              // 내 선박 등록하기
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: baseColor10,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(12.0),
                  ),
                ),
                height: 132,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '어선번호 입력하고 선박관리 한 번에!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: titleMedium,
                          color: baseColor50,
                          fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
                        ),
                      ),
                      marginHeight16,
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: baseColor10,
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: primaryColor50,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(12.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        height: 48,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '내 선박 등록하기',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: titleMedium,
                              fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
                              color: primaryColor50,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the `vessel_screen.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shipda/constants.dart';
import 'package:shipda/screens/vessel_screen/fishing_vessel/fishing_vessel_screen.dart';
import 'package:shipda/screens/vessel_screen/leisure_vessel/leisure_vessel_screen.dart';
import 'package:shipda/screens/vessel_screen/other_vessel/other_vessel_screen.dart';

class VesselScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const VesselScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: TabBar(
          indicatorColor: informationColor50,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: titleMedium,
            fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
          ),
          unselectedLabelColor: primaryColor50,
          labelColor: informationColor50,
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: '어선'),
            Tab(text: '레저선'),
            Tab(text: '특수선/기타선'),
          ],
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            FishingVesselScreen(),
            LeisureVesselScreen(),
            OtherVesselScreen(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvhH6.png)
[missing appear and bottomnavbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxbt5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your home_screen.dart, wrap the safe area in `Navigator` widget. This way, all the routes pushed will be inside the Scaffold of home_screen.dart

More info https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-bottom-navigation-bar-nested-routes-gorouter-beamer/

Comment: I deleted `SafeArea` in `home_screen.dart`, but still cannot find the AppBar and bottomNavigationBar. But the `Container()` is resized and looks better.

Answer (score 0):

This method can be applied and it will keep you away from all bottomnavbar problems

https://medium.com/flutter-community/everything-about-the-bottomnavigationbar-in-flutter-e99e5470dddb

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me. I changed my body to `body: IndexedStack(index: _selectedIndex, children: _widgetOptions)` as shown as the Medium.com.